# Node JS resuming execution based on event arrival

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node JS application that listens to events received from a socket of entity A and executes actions based on this events. This actions include calls to different entities (A included) based on promises chaining.

What I actually need to implement is a mechanism to call an action in entity A and execute a callback based on a new event and not based on A response. So the flow would be:

```
return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    run action1();
    .then(function (response) {
        return action2();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return action3();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        // code to wait for an event to arrive and resume this
    })
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Actually i don't know how it can be achieved.

Comment: What is `run action`? Does it return a promise? Why have you written a semi-colon after it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need the surrounding `new Promise`, it would seem. Assuming `run_action` returns a promise, then just:

```
return run_action1()
    .then(function (response) {
        return action2();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return action3();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            listen(resolve);
        });
    })
   .then(somethingElse);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I want to know is how the listen function would be implemented, supposing that listen will wait until the event arrives. And also what should I call when the event arrives in order to resume execution.

Comment: You write the listen function to do whatever is necessary to listen to whatever event from whatever event emitter you are using, typically something like `thing.on("event", resolve)`. You don't need to call anything when the event arrives in order to resume execution. That's what promises do for you. When the promise is resolved, the function specified in the `then` method will be executed.